# MySQL. Выборка, где диапазон дат имеет конкретные дни недели

Tags: база-данных, mysql

Добрый день!
В таблице хранятся `start_interval` и `end_interval`. Как из диапазона(`start_interval` - `end_interval`) вывести диапазоны, которые имеют конкретные дни недели(Пн, Вт и т.д.).
Спасибо!

> UPD:

```
start_interval               end_interval
'2012-10-01 03:30:00'(Пн)    '2012-10-03 03:30:00'(Ср)
'2012-10-02 03:30:00'(Вт)    '2012-10-05 03:30:00'(Пт)
'2012-10-03 03:30:00'(Ср)    '2012-10-06 03:30:00'(Сб)
```

Необходима выборка, где в интервал входит например Чт, соответственно:

```
start_interval               end_interval
'2012-10-02 03:30:00'(Вт)    '2012-10-07 03:30:00'(Пт)
'2012-10-03 03:30:00'(Ср)    '2012-10-09 03:30:00'(Сб)
```

Comment: Покажите, пожалуйста, пару записей из бд и покажите то, что бы вы хотели получить в итоге по выборке.

Comment: @ua6xh, я тут не писал код как боевой. Просто привел пример)

Answer (score 4):

Немного изменённый вариант пользователя [@dimka3210](/users/6447/dimka3210)

```
WHERE WEEKDAY(start_interval) < 4 AND WEEKDAY(end_interval) > 4
```

Код на [SQLFiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/151b3/5)

Comment: @idd - думал думал, и понял - даты будут в рамках одной недели? 
Если старт будет в пн, а энд будет в следующий пн, то выборка не сработает. Надо подумать над подсчетом дней.

Comment: Если сделать WHERE WEEKDAY(start_interval) >= 4 AND WEEKDAY(end_interval) <= 4, то условие выполниться правильно, ведь здесь не важно количество, а важно лишь попадание на указанный день

Comment: Да, но если даты будут такие: Сб(6)->Пт следующей недели(5), то условие не сработает, а четверг находится в интервале.
Или такой вариант: Ср(3)->Ср следующей недели(3), и опять условие на сработает. Пару идей есть, позже подумаю.

Comment: Да, здесь я с Вами согласен

Comment: @idd - сегодня SQLFiddle не хочет работать...

Answer (score 2):

```
WHERE WEEKDAY(start_interval) >= 0 AND WEEKDAY(end_interval) < 4
```

Если я правильно Вас понял.
Дни по номерам от 0 до 6

Comment: @dimka3210 - у вас в выборку попадет только первая запись.